# has_one :through association incorrectly returns nil for a new_record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations, has-one-through

I have the following models. Yes, the design is slightly convoluted, because we're revamping our architecture in stages; nonetheless, I think the principles here should work:

```
class Translation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :translation_service_option
  belongs_to :service, inverse_of: :translation, class_name: "TranslationService"
  # I have also tried belongs_to :translation_service, inverse_of: :translation, foreign_key: :service_id
end

class TranslationService < Service
  # Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :translation, inverse_of: :service
  # I have also tried inverse_of: :translation_service in conjunction with above
  has_one :translation_service_option, through: :translation
end
```

I am trying to build a before_save callback on TranslationService that needs to access translation_service_option, however, this is returning nil for a new record:

```
t = Translation.last
#=> #<Translation id: 154, translation_service_option_id: 5, [...]
t.service = TranslationService.new
#=> #<TranslationService id: nil [...]
t.translation_service_option
#=> #<TranslationServiceOption id: 5 [...]
t.service.translation_service_option
#=> nil
t.service.translation
#=> #<Translation id: 154 [...]
t.service.translation.translation_service_option
#=> #<TranslationServiceOption id: 5
```

Of course, once I save the object, it works fine, but the issue is I need access to it in the before_save (or before_create) callback:

```
t.service.save
t.translation_service_option
#=> #<TranslationServiceOption [...]
```

So the problem is that `t.service` returns nil for its `translation_service_option`, even though `t.service.translation` has a valid `translation_service_option`.

I get that `t.service` doesn't have an id yet, it *does* know about it's `translation` object. So why can't it also know about it's `translation_service_option` object? Obviously I could just use `self.translation.try(:translation_service_option)` in my callback, but that starts to get messy as the callback uses methods that are used more generally, and so just for this one quirk I find myself needing to replace all uses of `translation_service_option` with `translation.try(:translation_service_option)`, which just seems too un-Railsy and negates the purpose of setting up the `has_one :through` association in the first place.

Is there a way I can set up my associations to correctly assign `t.service.translation_service_option` on initialize?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. `ActiveRecord::Base` is necessary for `has_one` method and you don't inherit from `Translate` but from `Service` where is nowhere mentioned.

Comment: Service inherits from`ActiveRecord::Base`, I have added a comment to clarify this. The models work fine when they are saved, the only issue is when they are new records and the `has_one :through` association returns nil.

Comment: You're right in that the design is convoluted. And no - I don't believe you can do that query since the inverse in the relation has not been persisted. I would consider if you really need to use a model callback - you might just be building some very tight and messy couplings around some poor architecture choices.

Comment: Well pardon the convolution, but there are a lot of requirements from the business side that mean I can't revamp the whole thing in one go unfortunately. In any case, the only relation that hasn't been persisted is one that Rails already knows how to work around: the `TranslationService` hasn't been persisted but has access to its `translation` and the `translation` has access to its `translation_service_option` (which is persisted). What I don't understand then is how come the `TranslationService` can look up its `translation` but not `translation_service_option`?

Comment: As far as I need it for the backfill, this at least works though I would not accept this as a permanent solution for all future calls to create a TranslationService object: `t.service = TranslationService.new(translation_service_option: t.translation_service_option)`